Where do I find the email used here
I was making some easy changes on my site but I can't find where the accual email address is located that I want to change.
The code below is using some type of variable of dynamic method to reference the email.
I don't know what file it may be stored in
Thanks
Steve
<div class="contact-holder">
                            <i class="icon-mail"></i>
                            <a  class="contact" href="mailto:&#099;&#111;&#110;&#116;&#097;&#099;&#116;&#064;&#083;&#101;&#108;&#108;&#077;&#121;&#068;&#105;&#097;&#098;&#101;&#116;&#105;&#099;&#084;&#101;&#115;&#116;&#083;&#116;&#114;&#105;&#112;&#115;&#046;&#099;&#111;&#109;">&#099;&#111;&#110;&#116;&#097;&#099;&#116;&#064;&#083;&#101;&#108;&#108;&#077;&#121;&#068;&#105;&#097;&#098;&#101;&#116;&#105;&#099;&#084;&#101;&#115;&#116;&#083;&#116;&#114;&#105;&#112;&#115;&#046;&#099;&#111;&#109;</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="img-man-holder">
                        <img src="images/img1-4.png" alt="image description">
                    </div>

I searched in the file that this code is in but the accual email I'm looking to change is not there

The e-mail address is right where you probably expected it, next to the mailto:. The only trick applied is that instead of writing the verbatim letters, using the character codes as HTML entities to mask the actual characters (maybe in an attempt to lower the chance of site-scrapers to collect the address for nefarious purposes).
For instance, the first three letters are:
&#099;&#111;&#110;
Using a regular ASCII chart, it becomes clear quickly that characters 99, 111, and 110, respectively, are c, o, and n.
You an either look up the remaining character codes like this, or use one of the various HTML entity decoders available for online or local use.

FWIW, the reasoning and process is outlined here: https://owasp.org/www-project-proactive-controls/v3/en/c4-encode-escape-data

@AdrianJ.Moreno: As we're dealing with a hard-coded text inserted by the page author here, I'm not convinced the rationale has much to do with this case, but in cases where data from other sources is integrated in HTML, that's a valuable read.

Awesome , thanks for this valuable information. I did not know this.
